# GNU screen hangs on the pandaboard

Tags: gnu-screen

I've installed the [headless 11.04 variant](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/OMAP) of Ubuntu on my pandaboard. Most things seem to work correctly, but when I launch screen bash seems to hang and I must kill it using ctrl-z kill %1 in order to continue.

Has anyone been able to use screen on the pandaboard? Any good leads about how to debug this unfortunate behavior?

When I start an strace debug I get the following messages:

```
mprotect(0x4008b000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0x40123000, 30983)               = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=4*1024}) = 0
close(1023)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1022)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1021)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1020)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1019)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1018)                             = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
...
```

The close messages continues for some time then it says:

```
Directory '/var/run/screen' must have mode 775.
```

Following the chmod screen hangs again. A new strace screen reveals:

```
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40084000
write(1, "Directory '/var/run/screen' must"..., 49Directory '/var/run/screen' must have mode 777.
) = 49
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

In either case it seems broken...

Comment: GNU screen works fine by default in 11.10 on the pandaboard

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!